# How to handle several same unblocked signals in Python?

Tags: python, unix, signals, handler

Please see following python code:

```
signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, range(1, signal.NSIG)) #block signals
time.sleep(60) #waiting 60 seconds
pending = signal.sigpending() #check how much signals in pending state
```

When application is sleep I am sending for example five SIGUSR1 signals, but I received only one SIGUSR1 signal in pending. 
**Can I receive all SIGUSR1 signals which were sent ?**

Comment: Most signals do not queue up multiple instances - they are simply pending  or not. If you need to queue multiple instances of something, you need a more general event or message delivery framework.

Comment: twalberg, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python via Signal module do not queue up multiple instances of one type signal. When your application is sleep you will receive all signals which were sent, but after this you can detect only one the latest signal.